# If Extract >= 600 then do this in imacro Error

Tags: imacros

I am writing a macro code that should work like this:

1. Open the link provided - *no errors*
2. Extract the specified text - *no errors*
3. Remove the unnecessary text, leaving the number from the extract -
   *no errors*
4. Store the number from the extract in to a variable "FF" - *no errors*
5. Make a windows prompt and show the number extracted - *no errors*
6. Text or check if the extracted number is greater than or equal to
   600 - ***NOT WORKING, see errors below***
7. Make another windows prompt and say "GREATER THAN 600" if the
   condition is met, if false say "LOWER THAN 600" - ***NOT WORKING
   ALSO***

Anyone could point out and correct the codes?  I'm sorry and thank you very much for your help.

```
TAB T=1
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
URL GOTO=https://www.instagram.com/user/

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:/user/following/ EXTRACT=TXT

'removes the unnecessary text 
SET FF EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.replace(\"following\", \"\");")

PROMPT {{FF}}

SET !VAR1 EVAL("var FF="{{!EXTRACT}}\"; if(FF==663) alert("GREATER THAN 600"); else alert("LOWER THAN 600");")
```

**Error Encounter:**

MacroSyntaxError: wrong format of SET command, line 13 (Error code: -910)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your SET is that you didn't explicitly set the return value at the end, you ended with your if-cases.
As per http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL

> You need to explicitly return the final value by adding it as a single statement to the end of the Javascript.

```
Correct: SET myVal EVAL("var x = 1; x;") // myVal = 1 
Incorrect: SET myVal EVAL("var x = 1;") // myVal = null
```

If you just want to output these texts depending on whether or not the number is bigger than 600, this would do:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("\"{{FF}}\" >= 600 ? \"GREATER THAN 600\" : \"LOWER THAN 600\";")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

Note that your *EXTRACT* does not hold the number but the String still containing *following*, so use your stripped *FF* variable as input instead.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, but it wasn't extract the text, so I made an XPATH reference and extracted the text. If you want to use this refer [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-XPath-Using-Firebug), in the link I'd suggest the chrome method. anyway one important note regarding the eval function.

> For the eval function, the code evaluation occurs in an execution context that is separate from the browser process, therefore access to the web page DOM is not available.

**Reference:** [imacros forums](http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=26482)

So I suggest that you use the PROMPT function to show the output to the user.

**CODE:**

```
TAB T=1
'SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 15 
URL GOTO=https://www.instagram.com/user/

TAG XPATH="//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/header/div[2]/ul/li[3]/span/span" EXTRACT=TXT

SET !VAR1 EVAL("var FF=parseInt(\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"); if(FF==663) var temp = 'GREATER THAN 600'; else var temp = 'LOWER THAN 600';temp;")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```